# Single stored procedure for all insert query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

In programming languages we can make class library to reuse code. Is there any way to write a single SQL stored procedure that I can use every time? Like from ASP.NET code behind I will pass table name, number of columns, data types and values for an insert query, then the procedure will create the field dynamically and execute.

If there have any way to do that, please give me a proper guidance or an example with explanation.

Comment: tag anyone, `mysql` or `sql server`. they both are different platform.

Comment: sql server tagged

Comment: and you want to create table from front end by passing table name and schema ?Also want to insert data into it.

Comment: Its possible but wrong. Unfortunately SQL Server is not designed for that sort of code-reuse. Don't do it, don't even think about doing it. Not only could it be dangerous, but performance will most likely be terrible.

Comment: While you *might* be able to hack something like this together, it's a **horribly bad** idea in the SQL Server space - and in general. **Don't do this!** You should always honor the **Single Responsibility Principles** - a piece of code should do one thing, and one thing only - these "do-it-all" approaches might *sound good* at first, but they tend to develop into awful maintenance nightmares.....

Comment: @DarkRob No table Can be Created inside else where

Comment: @DaleBurrell Why there will be performance issue And why it is dangerous ? Can you plz explain

Comment: Dangerous, see answer below about sql injection, one mistake in building your dynamic SQL and you trash your database. Performance will most likely be bad because SQL Server can't optimise queries as easily when they are dynamically created as when they are fixed and known.

Comment: @marc_s Can you give me a scenario where maintenance nightmare can occur ? I am a novice in this field so that will be help for me

Comment: @DaleBurrell Okay, I understand the performance issue. But if i pass parameter how it could be so vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: Because you have to then build your SQL dynamically

Comment: @DaleBurrel Is there any other way to re use store procedure? And I think SQL Injection can be prevented in case of dynamic query. Need to validate check input parameter on server side also for get ridding of vulnerability.

Comment: @Priom you question is too generic, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Re-using SQL is not recommended, that is the advice of experts... what is your reasoning for persisting with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196981/discussion-between-priom-and-dale-burrell).

Answer (score 0):

This is is a very dangerous path. Do a search for *sql injection* to get an idea why.

A better way is to call specific stored procedures in the database from your application. That separates the UI code from the data access code, and can distribute the load in larger applications.

Comment: if i pass parameter how it could be so vulnerable to sql injection?